# Most efficient way to serialize a struct?

Tags: string, performance, serialization, encode

I want to minimize the amount of space for storing a struct. I store it in a redis-like string-string key-value cache.

Consider I have following struct:

```
struct UserSessionData:
   attr1 = Enum(class1)
   attr2 = Enum(class2)
   attr3 = string
```

- Naive approach is to store them with JSON::encode: `'{'attr1'='val1','attr2'='val2','attr3'='val3'}'`
- Better approach (space-wise) is to store only values as CSV: `'val1,val2,val3'`

I know I can compress it more because struct has `enum`s which are predefined values.
Any ideas to further minimize it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question; I used `PHP\gzcompress`. It resulted in almost 50% data compression in string. I'm sure there are other compression equivalents for other programming languages, leaving this answer here, hoping that it will be a reference for other researchers.